# Perl libwhisker library

Tags: perl, security, penetration-testing

Could someone provide links for tutorial about [libwhisker library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whisker/)?

Answer (score 2):

The libwhisker tarball has a lot of examples in the `scripts` subdirectory that provide working, well-commented code. The `README` file guides you to `api_demo.pl` as a starting point. If you're looking for a more textual approach, there's a (rather old) [article on SecurityFocus](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1798).